# Can't open project structure in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, multi-module

I have a multi-module project in IntelliJ (2018.3) and for some reasons I can't access the project structure anymore. When I click here
[image]

nothing happens. Also I tried to add a new child-module. An .iml file is added, but the new module is nowhere to be found. This is very annoying.

I tried to reimport the projet from GitHub, using the last commit. It didn't help.

Did anyone already have this problem and know how to resolve it?

---

Here the idea.log file :

```
2019-07-29 09:41:32,051 [501751407]  ERROR - figuration.ModulesConfigurator - IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5  Build #IU-183.5912.21 
2019-07-29 09:41:32,051 [501751407]  ERROR - figuration.ModulesConfigurator - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2019-07-29 09:41:32,051 [501751407]  ERROR - figuration.ModulesConfigurator - OS: Mac OS X 
2019-07-29 09:41:32,052 [501751408]  ERROR - figuration.ModulesConfigurator - Last Action: ShowProjectStructureSettings 
2019-07-29 09:41:32,078 [501751434]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Trying to initialize for different entity Project '/Users/admin/Documents/PROGRAMMING/OPENCLASSROOMS/P7/Apps_P7/WebserviceApp' p7-webservice-app, was originally initialized for Project (Disposed) applicationescalade 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Trying to initialize for different entity Project '/Users/admin/Documents/PROGRAMMING/OPENCLASSROOMS/P7/Apps_P7/WebserviceApp' p7-webservice-app, was originally initialized for Project (Disposed) applicationescalade
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.flex.projectStructure.LazyInitializer.ensureInitialized(LazyInitializer.java:16)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.flex.projectStructure.FlexBCConfigurator.reset(FlexBCConfigurator.java:132)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.flex.projectStructure.FlexBuildConfigurationsExtension.reset(FlexBuildConfigurationsExtension.java:62)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.projectRoot.ModuleStructureConfigurable.reset(ModuleStructureConfigurable.java:355)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.ProjectStructureConfigurable.reset(ProjectStructureConfigurable.java:354)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:95)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowStructureSettingsAction$1.<init>(ShowStructureSettingsAction.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowStructureSettingsAction.showDialog(ShowStructureSettingsAction.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowStructureSettingsAction.actionPerformed(ShowStructureSettingsAction.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:258)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:273)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher$1.performAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:618)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.lambda$processAction$2(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:667)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:195)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:666)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processActionOrWaitSecondStroke(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:519)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.inInitState(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:474)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:211)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:643)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:363)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2019-07-29 09:41:32,079 [501751435]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5  Build #IU-183.5912.21 
2019-07-29 09:41:32,079 [501751435]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2019-07-29 09:41:32,079 [501751435]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X 
2019-07-29 09:41:32,080 [501751436]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: ShowProjectStructureSettings 
2019-07-29 09:42:43,460 [501822816]  ERROR - figuration.ModulesConfigurator - module editors was not disposed 
java.lang.Throwable: module editors was not disposed
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:134)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.ModulesConfigurator.c(ModulesConfigurator.java:186)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1057)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.ModulesConfigurator.resetModuleEditors(ModulesConfigurator.java:184)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.projectRoot.StructureConfigurableContext.reset(StructureConfigurableContext.java:173)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.ProjectStructureConfigurable.reset(ProjectStructureConfigurable.java:342)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:95)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowStructureSettingsAction$1.<init>(ShowStructureSettingsAction.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowStructureSettingsAction.showDialog(ShowStructureSettingsAction.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowStructureSettingsAction.actionPerformed(ShowStructureSettingsAction.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:258)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:273)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher$1.performAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:618)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.lambda$processAction$2(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:667)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:195)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:666)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processActionOrWaitSecondStroke(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:519)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.inInitState(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:474)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:211)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:643)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:363)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2019-07-29 09:42:43,460 [501822816]  ERROR - figuration.ModulesConfigurator - IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5  Build #IU-183.5912.21 
2019-07-29 09:42:43,460 [501822816]  ERROR - figuration.ModulesConfigurator - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2019-07-29 09:42:43,460 [501822816]  ERROR - figuration.ModulesConfigurator - OS: Mac OS X 
2019-07-29 09:42:43,461 [501822817]  ERROR - figuration.ModulesConfigurator - Last Action: ShowProjectStructureSettings 
2019-07-29 09:42:43,488 [501822844]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Trying to initialize for different entity Project '/Users/admin/Documents/PROGRAMMING/OPENCLASSROOMS/P7/Apps_P7/WebserviceApp' p7-webservice-app, was originally initialized for Project (Disposed) applicationescalade 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Trying to initialize for different entity Project '/Users/admin/Documents/PROGRAMMING/OPENCLASSROOMS/P7/Apps_P7/WebserviceApp' p7-webservice-app, was originally initialized for Project (Disposed) applicationescalade
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.flex.projectStructure.LazyInitializer.ensureInitialized(LazyInitializer.java:16)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.flex.projectStructure.FlexBCConfigurator.reset(FlexBCConfigurator.java:132)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.flex.projectStructure.FlexBuildConfigurationsExtension.reset(FlexBuildConfigurationsExtension.java:62)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.projectRoot.ModuleStructureConfigurable.reset(ModuleStructureConfigurable.java:355)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.ProjectStructureConfigurable.reset(ProjectStructureConfigurable.java:354)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:95)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowStructureSettingsAction$1.<init>(ShowStructureSettingsAction.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowStructureSettingsAction.showDialog(ShowStructureSettingsAction.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowStructureSettingsAction.actionPerformed(ShowStructureSettingsAction.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:258)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:273)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher$1.performAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:618)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.lambda$processAction$2(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:667)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:195)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:666)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processActionOrWaitSecondStroke(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:519)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.inInitState(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:474)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:211)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:643)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:363)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2019-07-29 09:42:43,488 [501822844]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5  Build #IU-183.5912.21 
2019-07-29 09:42:43,488 [501822844]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2019-07-29 09:42:43,488 [501822844]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X 
2019-07-29 09:42:43,489 [501822845]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: ShowProjectStructureSettings
```

Comment: There must be some exception in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085). Post it here to get more help. See also [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559-Start-Failed-Internal-error-recovering-IDE-to-the-working-state-after-the-critical-startup-error) and try the steps to recover your IDE. If nothing help, [file a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) with the logs attached.

Comment: The idea.log was too long to be allowed for posting here, put I put an excerpt. It shows indeed lot of errors. Also, I first thought that my problem was specific to this project, but unfortunately it isn't : i just can't access the project structure at all, in any project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a bug logged](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198675) with the same exceptions. It would help if you attach the full logs folder zipped there. See if the issue persists in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 release.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I upgraded to the 2019.2 version and it seens to have solved the problem. Here the link to the complete log : https://pastebin.com/wm2etZsj